# Ansible: YAML attribute as variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have this Ansible playbook:

```
  vars:
    a: "key"
    b: "value"
    something:
      "{{ a }}": "{{ b }}"
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ something | to_nice_yaml }}"
```

The output is:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "'{{ a }}': value\n"
}
```

How do I make this be `key: value` instead of `{{ a }}: value`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try set_fact:

```
tasks:
    - set_fact: something="{{ a }}:{{ b }}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that. I have a large dict, which contains config that is then dumped into yaml as a config for a daemon. I am not aware how would it be possible to set_fact for one attribute of that dict :(